# Extract Entire AWS Setup into storable Files or Deployment Package(s)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, version-control, extract

Is there some way to 'dehydrate' or extract an entire AWS setup? I have a small application that uses several AWS components, and I'd like to put the project on hiatus so I don't get charged every month.

I wrote / constructed the app directly through the various services' sites, such as VPN, RDS, etc. Is there some way I can extract my setup into files so I can save these files in Version Control, and 'rehydrate' them back into AWS when I want to re-setup my app?

I tried extracting pieces from Lambda and Event Bridge, but it seems like I can't just 'replay' these files using the CLI to re-create my application.

Specifically, I am looking to extract all code, settings, connections, etc. for:

- Lambda. Code, Env Variables, layers, scheduling thru Event Bridge
- IAM. Users, roles, permissions
- VPC. Subnets, Route tables, Internet gateways, Elastic IPs, NAT Gateways
- Event Bridge. Cron settings, connections to Lambda functions.
- RDS. MySQL instances. Would like to get all DDL. Data in tables is not required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Former2](https://former2.com/). It will scan your account and allow you to generate CloudFormation, Terraform, or Troposphere templates. It uses a browser plugin, but there is also a [CLI](https://github.com/iann0036/former2/blob/master/cli/README.md) for it.

Comment: This. This is exactly what I needed. Super helpful site/extension. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called [*Infrastructure as Code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code). The idea is to define your infrastructure as code and then deploy your infrastructure using that "code".

There are a lot of options in this space. To name a few:

1. [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io)
2. [Cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/)
3. [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/)
4. [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com)

All of those should allow you to import already existing resources. At least Terraform has a `import` command to import an already existing resource into your IaC project.

This way you could create a project that mirrors what you currently have in AWS.

Excluded are things that are strictly taken not AWS resources, like:

1. Code of your Lambdas
2. MySQL DDL

Depending on the Lambdas deployment "strategy" the code is either on S3 or was directly deployed to the Lambda service. If it is the first, you just need to find the S3 bucket etc and download the code from there. If it is the second you might need to copy and paste it by hand.

When it comes to your MySQL DDL you need to find tools to export that. But there are plenty tools out there to do this.

After you did that, you should be able to destroy all the AWS resources and then deploy them later on again from your new IaC.

Comment: Infrastructure as Code. Those were the words I needed to find. Thank you for the great suggestions.